# A similar inequality for the Dedekind psi function, than an inequality stated by Schinzel

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, arithmetic-functions

I would like to ask about the next question that seems to me interesting. I know an article that was written by Andrzej Schinzel in which he stated **Lemma 2**. In this post we denote the Dedekind psi function is defined for a positive integer $m>1$ as the arithmetic function

$$\psi(m)=m\prod_{\substack{p\mid m\\p\text{ prime}}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right),\tag{1}$$
with the definition $\psi(1)=1$. See the Wikipedia [*Dedekind psi function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_function). As refers Wikipedia it is the sequence *A001615* in the OEIS. I've edited several problems related to (problems involving) this interesting  arithmetic function, but I don't know much about it, this is the motivation of this question (the claims from Wikipedia or the comments in OEIS).

> **Question.** Consider $$\psi(y_1)+\ldots+\psi(y_t)\leq B(k)\tag{2}$$ over positive integers $y_i$ with $1\leq i\leq t$ and $B(k)=\operatorname{bound}(k)$ a suitable bound that is a function of the variable $k\geq 1$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Determine such suitable $B(k)$ with the purpose to get an upper bound $\mathcal{B}(k)$ of $$\operatorname{lcm}[y_1,\ldots,y_t],$$ that's to get a statement $$\operatorname{lcm}[y_1,\ldots,y_t]\leq \mathcal{B}(k).\tag{3}$$ **Many thanks.**

The function $\operatorname{lcm}[y_1,\dots,y_t]$ means the least common multiple. I'm inspired in the mentioned lemma from [1], and I'm asking what work can be done about it to get a statament at research level.

### References:

[1] A. Schinzel, *Around Pólya's Theorem on Prime Divisors of a Linear Recurrence*, Diophantine Equations, pages 225-233, TIFR edited by N. Saradha, Narosa Publishing House (2008).

Comment: I hope that the question is interesting. *I would like to dedicate the question, with all respect, to the memory of the professor.*

Comment: On the other hand I know that Michel Planat, if I refer well, stated an equivalent form of the Riemann hypothesis (*Riemann hypothesis from the Dedekind psi function*, **HAL Id: hal-00526454** from Archive ouverte HAL). I edit this comment if it is interesting for  this post.